# how to stop reloading the data in custom cell ? that data coming from JSON

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is my custom cell code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
ContestTableViewCell *cell = [myContestTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *myNib;
    myNib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ContestTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell =[myNib objectAtIndex:0];
}
if (selectedIndex==indexPath.row)
{
}
else
{
}
cell.fldExamTitleLbl.text = [fldExamTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.fldExamStartDateLbl.text = [fldExamStartArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.prizeMoney.text =[prizeMoneyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.firstReward.text = [firstRewardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.secondReward.text = [secondRewardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.thirdReward.text = [thirdRewardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

}
```

And didSelectRowAtIndexPath  i am writing this code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
{
    selectedIndex = -1;
    [myContestTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    return;
}
if (selectedIndex != -1)
{
    NSIndexPath *prevPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [myContestTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [myContestTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

I am getting Output like this it is reloading the data of JSON.
[image]

I am new to iOS please help me.

Comment: Gray area is part of your table?

Comment: no. white collar is my expandable cell

Comment: all cell has dynamic height ? or have a fixed height?

Comment: yes it is fixed to normal 100 and expandable 266 @jay

Comment: please check in your ContestTableViewCell.xib `clip SubViews` is selected or not .
if not selected then select it